# How do you get your money from your home tzedaka box to your favorite charity?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, money, product-recommendation

Okay now I have this tzedaka box sitting in my living room and it's full of coins and crumpled bills.  How do I give that to my favorite charity?  Or any charity?

Comment: I don't understand what's the question. You just take the coins and give them whoever you want. What do you mean *how*?

Comment: @jutky, suppose my favorite tzedaka doesn't accept coins, or it's not feasible to mail a bunch of coins.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67004

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has nothing to do with Judaism.

Comment: Write a check and mail it.

Comment: @mevaqesh tzedaka is an aspect of Judaism, and this question is on-topic. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/262/the-parameters-of-jewish-life-scope

Comment: @IsaacMoses [nope](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/8775/mevaqesh) It may be noted that since a consensus was never reached, letting users vote on a question by question basis may be the best bet. It may also be noted that the position you advocate can easily be construed as anything goes which would compromise the integrity of the SE.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Furthermore, this does not have to do with charity per se, but with loose change; it has equally to do with processing zeddaqa funds, as with processing money stolen from the bank.

Comment: @mevaqesh The appropriate place to critique my Meta answer or even better, provide an alternative policy proposal, is over there. Regarding your bank-robbing scenario, Judaism experts are significantly more likely to have good techniques for transforming change into *tzedaka* donations, particularly, than bank robbing experts.

Comment: Do you think those specific coins need to be transmitted to an appropriate recipient (i.e. that tzedaka money isn't fungible)?  If so, it would help to edit that in (along with any source for that).  If not, I don't understand why the question arises -- why not just write a check?

Answer (score 4):

Mail a check for the amount, put the money somewhere in your home, and start replenishing the now-empty tz'daka box....

Comment: If you're willing to count the coins yourself.  But then what do you do with the coins, if you don't want to use them as coins?  Take them to coinstar and lose a few percent; take them to coinstar and get an amazon gift card; other ideas?

Comment: See my answer: you start replenishing the box.

Answer (score 4):

I call [Colel Chabad](http://www.colelchabad.org/Contact_Us.bp). They send someone to my door with a bag for me to pour all the money in. A few weeks later I get a receipt in the mail for my donation.

Answer (score 3):

Take the coins to coinstar, and they'll count it and donate it all (no fee) to your choice of a handful of [major charities](http://coinstar.com/us/html/A2-1).  [None of them are specifically Jewish charities, but that's okay](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/350/jewish-definition-of-a-charity).

Take the bills to the bank, and write a check correspondingly.

Comment: Shalom: It's not ok to give the charity to non-Jewish orgs when Jewish orgs in need. We have narrow channel of donors, much smaller then the whole populace.  It's not ok man.

Comment: @RomanKagan we can debate priorities of allocation, but fundamentally we fall back on Gittin 61a: מפרנסים עניי נכרים עם עניי ישראל ומבקרין חולי נכרים עם חולי ישראל וקוברין מתי נכרים עם מתי ישראל. "We sustain the non-Jewish as well as Jewish poor; tend to the non-Jewish as well as Jewish sick; and bury the non-Jewish as well as Jewish dead, as such are the ways of peace."

Answer (score 1):

Give it to your synagogue office and let them figure it out?  How do they count the coins and bills?  How do they get the bank to take it?

Comment: you are supposed to answer the question, not make more questions

Answer (score 1):

If you buy lots of stuff from Amazon:

Take everything to coinstar and buy yourself an amazon gift card.  Then write out an equal check.

Answer (score 0):

About the bills:

Total up the bills. Mail a check to your favorite charity for the amount, then move the bills to your wallet. Later on, the charity will send you a tax receipt.

About the coins:

Dump all the coins into a charity box outside your home. Charities are good at handling large amounts of coins.

If the coins total more than $20, try to hand them directly to a charity employee or gabbai. Unfortunately, some people steal money from charities, including on erev Purim and erev Yom Kippur when there are dozens of collection pans set out on one table.

Tell the charity that you don't need a tax receipt for the coins.