# May one use Ma'aser (tithe) for non-Jewish charities?

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jewish definition of  a charity](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/350/jewish-definition-of-a-charity)

May one use one's Ma'aser (tithe) money to donate to non-Jewish charities, or is the requirement for Ma'aser only fulfilled if the recipient is Jewish or a Jewish institution (assume for purposes of the question that the institution engages in either religious practice or learning, or support of the needy, not a Jewish-oriented nonprofit - I think that may warrant a separate question.)?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think this question is substantially different from the one linked, mostly because it has a far more precise focus. Incidentally, several questions which are kal v'chomer dupes of the one linked (and which are dupes of each other) are still open.  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34974/donating-to-a-christian-charity  and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44676/giving-to-a-mission-collection?rq=1  Thanks

Comment: I'm with @SAH on this one -- more to the point, this question is specifically about *maaser*, which may or may not have the same rules as "charity," in the other question.