# Should one wish for the destruction of buildings of idol worship?

Tags: avodah-zarah, christianity, current-events

Two sequential questions, prompted by the [Notre Dame fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notre-Dame_de_Paris_fire):

1. Is one obligated to wish that places of idol worship are consumed if they already are on fire? (I would think so, given e.g. [OC 224:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.224.2?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en))
2. If so, and if [Christianity is considered idol worship](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89/759), does the unique importance of Notre Dame make this apply less?

The [Conference of European Rabbis](https://twitter.com/PinchasRabbi/status/1118109829820821504) and [others](https://www.jpost.com/Diaspora/The-soul-of-France-is-burning-French-Jews-shocked-by-Notre-Dame-blaze-586986) sent supportive messages *post facto*, but that could have been a) *mishum eiva* and/or b) sympathy for people, but not the building itself.

Comment: Open to an edit to a less provocative title.

Comment: I edited the title; see revision reason.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101932/15256

Comment: 1. Please elaborate on "*the unique importance of Notre Dame "*.

Comment: Just as an interesting fact, did you know that there was a prophecy by one Rabbi 600 years ago that Notre Dame would get burned because that's where they burned Gemara? Heard it in this shiur: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eCUPGGHjaE&t=2895s

Comment: Why would you not want places of idol worship to get destroyed?

Comment: @Dan Most assume the Talmud was not burned at Notre Dame nor is it clear the wish of that rabbi was towards a building and not the perpetrators. And it was 750 years ago.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you I just said what I heard in the shiur. Could you please provide sources i.e. the name of that Rabbi, who those "most" are, etc. Would be really interesting to study that issue in detail:)

Comment: @AlBerko To quote the CER: "Notre-Dame of Paris is a symbol of human ingenuity and endurance celebrating almost one thousand years of European and French culture and architecture." it's considered a treasure in its own right outside of its religious context.

Comment: @DanWeisberg you can think of this as a _limud zechus_.

Comment: @Arithmomaniac What do you expect from CER? To tell the truth? בכל דור ודור קמים עלינו לכלותנו and in all children Hagadahs the Christians are part of that saying alongside Pharaoh, the Greeks, the Russians, and the Nazis. Let's not forget.

Answer (score -3):

This is only a draft answer to N.D's fire:

1. As Rambam discusses in the non-censored version at the end of Hil. Melachim (I think) about the importance of Christianity in overall spreading the Word of G-d, it should be weighted against two aspects:

   - The possible problem of idolatry in certain branches of Christianity
   - The never-ending anti-semitism that took the lives of millions of Jews in the last two millennia.

   Therefore the implications of the destruction and/or restoration of a church must be weighted one against the other.
2. Idolatry is the antithesis to the reality to one G-d, so one who wishes to expand Hashem's presence in this world certainly must wish to annul idolatry in any way. And there are numerous verses in the Torah and Prophets that support this.

Answer (score -5):

You can "wish" for whatever you want.  Your thoughts are your own.  I am not sure you could control them anyway.  (Action is a different matter.)

Comment: Can I wish for my neighbor's wife?

Comment: @DoubleAA -- Please disclose the mechanism by which you can prevent yourself from having "bad" thoughts.  Most of us don't know it.

Comment: The question is not whether one can but whether one should...

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Ibn Ezra on tenth commandment, summarized here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77351/1852

Comment: @Arithmomaniac -- We are talking about "bad" thoughts entering your mind, not about coveting.  (For reference, the commandment against coveting applies only to things God said you cannot have, such as *your neighbor's* possessions.  It does not apply to the possessions themselves in the abstract.  For example, if your neighbor has a beautiful house, there is nothing wrong with you desiring to own a similar house and working hard to earn it.  Otherwise, how would you ever acquire anything if you did not desire it first?  The prohibition is against wanting your neighbor's house *specifically*.)