# What type of mitzvah, if any, is a donation to medical research?

Tags: mitzvah, tzedakah-charity, science

If I give money to a charity that finances medical research, I think I'm doing a mitzvah, but of what sort?  Is this tzedakah when I'm not clothing or feeding the poor?  Is it saving a life when there is a chance that my dollar might be spent on research that goes nowhere?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/350/jewish-definition-of-a-charity

Comment: Since when must one only try and save someone's life if the method is 100% certain to work?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, duplicate?