# What is the mitzvah of tzedakah dependent on?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, rambam, tzedakah-charity, pirke-avot-ethicsof

We learn in the Rambam commentary on Avos (3:19) that it is preferable to give a little bit of tzedakah to many people than  a few large amounts to a few people.

When does one fulfil the mitzvah of tzedakah; when one gives it each time or when one separates a large sum from his pay? Basically: are you considered to have fulfilled the mitzvah each time you give, which would complement the view of the Rambam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are two inter-related but separate *mitzvot* here**, one of *tzedakah* and another of *maaser*, separating from one's income (some opinions dispute if *maaser* is really a formal *mitzva* or a highly praiseworthy custom one should follow).

R Avrohom Chaim Feuer writes in his book [The tzedakah treasury](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578195145.html) (pp. 122ff)

> The mitzvah of *tzedakah* is really only half of the story of charity
>   distribution. The second half of the story is a separate mitzvah
>   called *maaser*, tithing, which serves to define exactly how much should
>   optimally be given away.
>
> A person who distributes *tzedakah* haphazardly, without specifically
>   setting aside *maaser*, has earned only the mitzvah of *tzedakah*. One
>   who carefully sets aside *maaser* and distributes it charitably has
>   gained two *mitzvos*, both *maaser* and *tzedakah.*

He explains further that by separating *maaser* one elevates the status of the money left, by demonstrating that everything is a present from God and even that which remains for personal use is truly God's gift. In a deeper sense, separating *maaser* demonstrates one has no absolute power on his possessions and all one owns is in partnership with Hashem.

Regarding giving away in small sums, businesshalacha [here](https://www.businesshalacha.com/en/newsletter/tzedakah-preference) explains this is beneficial to cultivate a trait of generosity, to support more people or to increase the chance one of the recipient will be really worthy. But others give counter examples, e.g., the Chofetz Chaim felt it was preferable to lend a larger amount if it will prevent that borrower from becoming destitute, since one also fulfills the mitzvah of supporting the poor.

Note the halacha codifies the idea of not giving to one person ([SA YD 257:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.257.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) but not the one to fragment one's *tzedakah* over many large gifts. R Shimon Taub in [The laws of tzedakah and maaser](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578195893.html) writes one should

> identify several poor people to receive a large donation which will
>   make a significant difference to them and disburse smaller donations
>   to many other indigents as well.

Also see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67389/11501) for a related answer on setting up a *maaser* system.

Comment: My other question was when is one considered to have fulfilled the mitzvah of tzedakah; each time one gives? Then it makes sense to give a little a mount to a lot of people.

Comment: I do not know. But it doesn't make sense to me that one giving 10x10 would get more *schar mitzva* than one giving 100 in one go. Otherwise no one would make larger donation. And I don't think we know what the reward is for one mitzva vs. another. There are reasons to give to multiple individuals but it is not to get more reward directly. But I don't really have a source for this yet

Comment: Doesn't a Mitzvah of _Ma'aser_ only apply to produce of the land?

Comment: @TamirEvan there is also a concept of *maaser ksafim* (based on [Bereshit 14:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.14.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) - some poskim think it is a mitzva from the Torah, some *mi'dRabbanan*, others that it is a *minhag* one should do, see e.g., beginning of https://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.com/2013/02/archives-hilchos-maaser-kesafim.html

Comment: I'm sorry. I missed the parenthetical remark in the first paragraph. Also, this is the first time I'm hearing of _Ma'aser Kesafim_ being treated as a _Mitzvah_.